# Hide tab bar tab or disable it?

Tags: ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

About to release an iPhone app that has five tab bar buttons.

One of the buttons will be used for functionality that is in a future e.g. 1.1. release.
As a result of this, is it better for me to disable the tab bar tab in IB or should I remove it all together from the tab bar?

Is it likely that the app would get rejected by Apple if I leave the tab bar button in but disabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the component, just hide it instead of disabling it.